# Dart asset vs web directories?

Tags: resources, dart, project-structure

I've seen Dart code that places all CSS, HTML, JS, images, etc. in an `asset` subdirectory, and other projects that place those same files under a `web` directory. Even the Dart [package layout spec](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html) is ambiguous on the subject.

So I ask: when to put client-side resources under `asset`, and when to put them under `web`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new feature/convention. 
The problem is, that the web server integrated into Darteditor doesn't yet support the asset directory. It's only supported by pub serve yet. But I guess Darteditor will support it soon and then this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @zoechi (+1) - but the way you wrote your answer, I have no idea what you're referring to when you say "this". Which of the two directories do I place client resources (CSS, HTML, images, etc.) into? `web` or `asset`? Thanks again!

Comment: sorry for the confusion. asset is new.

Comment: Thanks again @zoechi (+1). Sorry, one last followup: if `asset` is the new place, then is `web` totally "deprecated" and no longer encouraged for use? Thanks again!

Comment: AFAIK asset should contain static resources. Dart code and HTML your Dart code works with goes to web.